# Is this glued function convex?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, inequality, convex-analysis

Define a function $F:[0, \infty) \to \mathbb R$ by
$$F(s) :=
\begin{cases}
2(\sqrt{s}-1)^2,  & \text{ if  }\, s \ge \frac{1}{4} \\
1-2s, & \text{ if  }\, s \le \frac{1}{4}
\end{cases}
$$

> Is $F$ convex? This seems plausible from looking at its graph.

It is not hard to see that the restrictions $F|_{[0,\frac{1}{4}]},F|_{[\frac{1}{4},\infty)}$ are convex. Is there an elegant way to show that the combined definition also produces a convex function on the entire domain $[0, \infty)$?

*My motivation for studying this function comes from [this optimization problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278523/finding-the-closest-matrix-to-textso-n-with-a-given-determinant).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $F\in\mathcal C^1(\mathbb R)$ and $$F'(s)=\begin{cases}
 -2, & s\le\frac{1}{4}, \\
 2\left(1-\frac1{\sqrt{s}}\right), & s\geq\frac14
\end{cases}$$

which is non-decreasing so that $F$ is convex.

Comment: Thanks, this proof is nice and simple.

Comment: This would even work if $F'(\frac14)$ did not exist (but $F'$ would be non-decreasing across that point nonetheless)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen This sounds interesting. You are saying that non-differentiability at a single point does not affect the convexity of the function (assuming $F'$ is non-decreasing on its domain of existence). Is it trivial?